# Arrange 3 dynamic number of inputs in a row and action on two columns of inputs based on third column

Tags: r, user-interface, dynamic, shiny

I am building a shiny app to map two different text inputs. I do the matching using string distances but they might be erroneous. So, I am planning to develop  a shiny app where the subject matter experts can use the click and dropdown to select match unique data.

If I have fixed number of rows, I can achieve something like below:: However, when I don't know the number of rows in data, how can I dynamically design user-interface to get the required output?

After the user have performed the required mapping. I want to perform some action after the button click. Additionally, if the user has clicked mapped (the check box). I want to leave that row out of the final action.

```
library(shiny)
set.seed(42)
n_samp = 5 # this comes from the input
indx <- sample(1:20, n_samp)

let_small <-  letters[indx]
let_caps  <-  sample(LETTERS[indx])

# user input
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "n_samp_choice", label = NULL, 
              choices = 1:20, width = 500), # number of samples
  fluidRow( # first row checkbox
    column(width = 2, offset = 0,
           checkboxInput("correct1", label = NULL, FALSE)
    ),
    column(width = 2, offset = 0,  # text input originial
           textInput(inputId = "original1", value = let_small[1], label = NULL )
    ),
    column(width = 5, # options for match
           selectInput(inputId = "options1", label = NULL, 
                       choices = let_caps, width = 500)
    )
  ), 
  fluidRow( 
    column(width = 2, offset = 0,
           checkboxInput("correct1", label = NULL, FALSE)
    ),
    column(width = 2, offset = 0,
           textInput(inputId = "original2", value = let_small[2], label = NULL )
    ),
    column(width = 5,
           selectInput(inputId = "options2", label = NULL, 
                       choices = let_caps, width = 500)
    )
  ), 
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 2, offset = 0,
           checkboxInput("correct1", label = NULL, FALSE)
    ),
    column(width = 2, offset = 0,
           textInput(inputId = "original3", value = let_small[3], label = NULL )
    ),
    column(width = 5,
           selectInput(inputId = "options3", label = NULL, 
                       choices = let_caps, width = 500)
    )
  ), 
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 2, offset = 0,
           checkboxInput("correct1", label = NULL, FALSE)
    ),
    column(width = 2, offset = 0,
           textInput(inputId = "original4", value = let_small[4], label = NULL )
    ),
    column(width = 5,
           selectInput(inputId = "options4", label = NULL, 
                       choices = let_caps, width = 500)
    )
  ), 
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 2, offset = 0,
           checkboxInput("correct1", label = NULL, FALSE)
    ),
    column(width = 2, offset = 0,
           textInput(inputId = "original5", value = let_small[5], label = NULL )
    ),
    column(width = 5,
           selectInput(inputId = "options5", label = NULL, 
                       choices = let_caps, width = 500)
    ),
    column(width = 2, offset = 0,
           uiOutput("actionBut.out")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$actionBut.out <- renderUI({
    print(input$original1)
    session$sendCustomMessage(type="jsCode",
                              list(code= "$('#text').prop('disabled',true)"))
    actionButton("copyButton1","Copy Code")
  })

  observeEvent(input$copyButton1, {

    if(tolower(input$options1) == tolower(input$options1) &
       tolower(input$options2) == tolower(input$options2) &
       tolower(input$options3) == tolower(input$options3) &
       tolower(input$options4) == tolower(input$options4) &
       tolower(input$options5) == tolower(input$options5))
    {
      print("great job")
    }else{
      unmapp <-  which(c(input$correct1, input$correct2, 
                         input$correct3, input$correct4, 
                         input$correct5))
      print("The following are unmatched")
      print(let_caps[unmapp])
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dynamic design using [Shiny Modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) and [UIOutput](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html).

**Step1**: Create a module to be called by a loop:

```
moduleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fluidRow( # first row checkbox
      column(width = 2, offset = 0,
             checkboxInput(ns("correct"), label = NULL, FALSE)
      ),
      column(width = 2, offset = 0,  # text input originial
             textInput(inputId = ns("original"), value = let_small[id], label = NULL )
      ),
      column(width = 5, # options for match
             selectInput(inputId = ns("options"), label = NULL, 
                         choices = let_caps, width = 500)
      )
    )
  )
}
```

**Step2**: Create a `UIOutput`, that will serve as a placeholder for the module.

```
uiOutput("module_placeholder")
```

**Step3**: Add server logic:

I added a `numericInput` that allows you to simulate different number of rows. E.g.: If you set it to 5, the module will be generated 5 times.

This `observer` allows you to generate any number of instances of the module.

```
observe( {
    output$module_placeholder <- renderUI( {
      lapply(1:input$num, moduleUI)
    })
  })
```

The `id`s of the objects will be `1-correct`, `1-original`, `1-options` for the first module, `2-correct`, `2-original`, etc. for the second module, ...

It is important because you can access input elements using input[[NAME_OF_THE_ELEMENT]].

So for example I use `lapply` to check if `input$original == input$options` for every module. (Similar to your code, but it's general, so it works for any number of modules)

```
cond <- unlist(lapply(to_check, function(x) {
  tolower(input[[paste(x, "original", sep="-")]]) == tolower(input[[paste(x, "options", sep="-")]])
}))
```

**See full code**:

```
library(shiny)
set.seed(42)
n_samp = 10 # this comes from the input
indx <- sample(1:20, n_samp)

let_small <-  letters[indx]
let_caps  <-  sample(LETTERS[indx])


moduleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fluidRow( # first row checkbox
      column(width = 2, offset = 0,
             checkboxInput(ns("correct"), label = NULL, FALSE)
      ),
      column(width = 2, offset = 0,  # text input originial
             textInput(inputId = ns("original"), value = let_small[id], label = NULL )
      ),
      column(width = 5, # options for match
             selectInput(inputId = ns("options"), label = NULL, 
                         choices = let_caps, width = 500)
      )
    )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "num", label = "Select number of modules", value = 1, min = 1),
  selectInput(inputId = "n_samp_choice", label = NULL, 
              choices = 1:20, width = 500), # number of samples
  uiOutput("module_placeholder"),
  uiOutput("actionBut.out")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe( {
    output$module_placeholder <- renderUI( {
      lapply(1:input$num, moduleUI)
    })
  })

  output$actionBut.out <- renderUI({
    print(input$original1)
    session$sendCustomMessage(type="jsCode",
                              list(code= "$('#text').prop('disabled',true)"))
    actionButton("copyButton","Copy Code")
  })

  observeEvent(input$copyButton, {
    checked <- unlist(lapply(1:input$num, function(x) {
      if(input[[paste(x, "correct", sep="-")]]) x
    }))

    if(length(checked) == 0) {
      to_check <- 1:input$num
    } else {
      to_check <- (1:input$num)[-checked]
    }

    cond <- unlist(lapply(to_check, function(x) {
      tolower(input[[paste(x, "original", sep="-")]]) == tolower(input[[paste(x, "options", sep="-")]])
    }))

    if(all(cond)) {
      print("great job")
    } else {
      unmapp <-  which(!cond)
      optns <- unlist(lapply(1:input$num, function(x) {
        input[[paste(x, "options", sep="-")]]
      }))
      print("The following are unmatched")
      print(optns[to_check][unmapp])
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 uiOutput("mappings")
```

where you have the inputs now and in the server you place something like this

```
output$mappings <- renderUI({
  tagList(
    lapply(
      1:length(someList),
      function(idx){
        fluidRow( # first row checkbox
          column(width = 2, offset = 0,
                 checkboxInput(paste0("correct",idx), label = NULL, FALSE)
          ),
          column(width = 2, offset = 0,  # text input originial
                 textInput(inputId = paste0("original",idx), value = let_small[1], label = NULL )
          ),
          column(width = 5, # options for match
                 selectInput(inputId = paste0("options",idx), label = NULL, 
                             choices = let_caps, width = 500)
          )
        )
      }
    )
  )
})
```

to then get the values you can do something like this

```
observe({
  lapply(
    1:length(someList),
    function(idx){input[[paste0("correct",idx)]]}
  )
})
```

taking your example it could look something like this

```
library(shiny)
set.seed(42)
n_samp = 5 # this comes from the input
indx <- sample(1:20, n_samp)

let_small <-  letters[indx]
let_caps  <-  sample(LETTERS[indx])

# user input
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "n_samp_choice", label = NULL, 
              choices = 1:20, width = 500), # number of samples
  uiOutput("mappings"),

)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$actionBut.out <- renderUI({
    print(input$original1)
    session$sendCustomMessage(type="jsCode",
                              list(code= "$('#text').prop('disabled',true)"))
    actionButton("copyButton1","Copy Code")
  })
  output$mappings <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      lapply(
        1:5,
        function(idx){
          fluidRow( # first row checkbox
            column(width = 2, offset = 0,
                   checkboxInput(paste0("correct",idx), label = NULL, FALSE)
            ),
            column(width = 2, offset = 0,  # text input originial
                   textInput(inputId = paste0("original",idx), value = let_small[idx], label = NULL )
            ),
            column(width = 5, # options for match
                   selectInput(inputId = paste0("options",idx), label = NULL, 
                               choices = let_caps, width = 500)
            )
          )
        }
      )
    )
  })

  lapply(
    1:5,
    function(idx){
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("options",idx)]],
                   {
                     print(input[[paste0("options",idx)]])
                   },
                   ignoreInit = TRUE)
    }
  )
  observeEvent(input$copyButton1, {

    if(tolower(input$options1) == tolower(input$options1) &
       tolower(input$options2) == tolower(input$options2) &
       tolower(input$options3) == tolower(input$options3) &
       tolower(input$options4) == tolower(input$options4) &
       tolower(input$options5) == tolower(input$options5))
    {
      print("great job")
    }else{
      unmapp <-  which(c(input$correct1, input$correct2, 
                         input$correct3, input$correct4, 
                         input$correct5))
      print("The following are unmatched")
      print(let_caps[unmapp])
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```